# Warnings when restoring graphical parameters

Tags: r, plot, warnings, par

I am writing my first R package and currently working on a function to make a plot using some particular graphical parameters. I want the user defined graphical parameters to get restored after the plot is made but always get same warning messages:

```
opar <- par()
par(oma = c(5, 4, 0, 0) + 0.1, mar = c(0, 0, 1, 1) + 0.1)
par(opar)
```

> Warning messages:
>   1: In par(opar) : graphical parameter "cin" cannot be set
>   2: In par(opar) : graphical parameter "cra" cannot be set
>   3: In par(opar) : graphical parameter "csi" cannot be set
>   4: In par(opar) : graphical parameter "cxy" cannot be set
>   5: In par(opar) : graphical parameter "din" cannot be set
>   6: In par(opar) : graphical parameter "page" cannot be set

Is there a better way of doing that? I know the `suppressWarnings()` function but 1. I don't want the messages to get *hided* and 2. if the function is called two times, a warning message appears:

```
> There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Comment: Use `opar <- par(oma = ..., mar = ...)`, the returned value is the old values for *just* what you set. `par()` by itself includes everything, which is overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `...` in my comments were merely a *placeholder* for whatever you intend to put in there. (I tend to think lots of code in comments can be difficult to read, so I just shortened it.)

Literally:

```
opar <- par(oma = c(5, 4, 0, 0) + 0.1, mar = c(0, 0, 1, 1) + 0.1)
# other code that uses those settings
# when you are ready to reset to the original settings for oma and mar,
par(opar)
```

This is provided in a similar example in the doc, [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html).

One example of how doing it this way is different from saving all of the `par`ameters with `opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)` is that this only reset/restores the parameters that you explicitly changed. It is feasible that others might have changed as a side-effect of other actions (outside of this *intent*).

Answer (score 6):

You may go around these warnings by supplying `no.readonly = TRUE` when you save the graphical parameters, as follows:

```
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(oma = c(5, 4, 0, 0) + 0.1, mar = c(0, 0, 1, 1) + 0.1)
par(opar)
```

Also, you can restore the defaul `par` parameter values using `dev.off()` .

Hope it helps.

Comment: @r2evans' comment to the question is a better approach, because it only restores the parameters that you have changed.  In a complicated program yours might do too much.